# OrientDB use LIKE in an encapsulated field

Tags: json, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have an OrientDB table named `CalculationFunctionGroup`, in which I have a field named `functions`.

This field has JSON content like this:

`[{"@type":"d","@version":0,"@class":"CalculationFunction","name":"AR_0015_0280","code":"//AR_0015_0280 OTTIMIZZATA / FORMATTATA\nvar worka01 = anagPay(\"AR_0015_0280\", -1);\nreturn worka01;","language":"Javascript"}]`

I want to extract rows satisfying a LIKE condition on the `code` element of the JSON.

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT FROM CalculationFunctionGroup
WHERE functions.code LIKE '%OTTIMIZZATA%'
```

But the number of extracted rows is ZERO!

Comment: Hi, what is the type of the field named functions ? is a link ?

Comment: Hi, is a field with type EMBEDDEDLIST, not a link to another table

Comment: Hi, what is functions.code? Could you post the code of the class CalculationFunction? Because in the JSON file there isn't a function property.

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi: Hi, I'm using CalculationFunctionGroup table and not CalculationFunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select expand(distinct(rid))
from (select @rid,functions.code
      from CalculationFunctionGroup unwind functions)
where functions like "%OTTIMIZZATA%"
```

Comment: This query is unsatisfactory in general because it performs a match on `functions`, not on `functions.code` as specified by the OP.  Consider, for example, what would happen if "name" happened to contain the query string.